# Cant copy the whole text file to char array

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to copy a whole text file into char array using fstream but even upon increasing the size of the array it reads the text file to same limit .i am bount to save it in a char array and it will be good if it is not a dynamic one ??? any solution please ...

```
 // smallGrams.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

//#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

void readInput(const char* Path);
 void removePunctucationMarks();
 void removeSpacing();
 void insertDots();
 char * getText();
 void generateUnigrams();
  void generateBigrams();
  void generateTrigrams();
 double validateSentance(string str);
 string sentenceCreation(int position);

 int main()
 {
      char *path="alice.txt";
      readInput(path);

     return 0;
 }
 void readInput(const char* Path)
 {
     ifstream infile;


     infile.open(Path);

     if(!infile.fail())
         cout<<"File opened successfully"<<endl;
     else
         cout<<"File failed to open"<<endl;

     int arrSize=100000000;
     char *arr=new char[arrSize];
     int i=0;
     while(!infile.eof()&&i<arrSize)
     {
         infile.get(arr[i]);
         i++;
     }
     arr[i-1]='\0';
     for(short i=0;i<arrSize&&arr[i]!='\0';i++)
     {
         cout<<arr[i];
     }





 }
```

Comment: What is wrong with `std::string`?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen we are bound to use char array in the assignment

Comment: check by changing short to unsing int in the last for loop.

Comment: What are the contents of the file? What is the output? Have you debugged your code to see when exactly and under what conditions your loop ends? Do you know when the [`eof flag`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/eof/) is set and how [`get`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) works?

Comment: Not directly related to yopur question, but if the file fails to be opened, it's not going to end well

Comment: _we are bound to use char array in the assignment_ You may send your teacher this link: [Kate Gregory: Stop Teaching C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) (may be, anonymously.) ;-)

Comment: And you might have a problem here `for(short i=0;....` if `short` is a 16 bit type.

Comment: you need to create a version of  vector. When the capacity is full allocate a new memory with larger size.

Comment: You should get the size of the file before creating the array.  If you have a fixed capacity, you should use that to read the maximum characters.  See `std::ifstream::read()`.

Comment: BTW, your program continues to read a file if there was an issue opening it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a C style solution that works. It checks the file size and then allocate the necessary memory for the array and reads all the content of the file in one call. The fread() call returns the number of bytes you requested or an error has ocurred (check [fread()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/?kw=fread) reference)

```
# include <cstring>
# include <cstdlib>
# include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *data;
    int data_len;
    FILE *fd;

    fd = fopen ("file.txt", "r");
    if (fd == NULL) {
        // error
        return -1;
    }

    fseek (fd , 0 , SEEK_END);
    data_len = ftell (fd);
    rewind (fd);

    data = (char *) malloc ((data_len + 1) * sizeof (char));
    memset (data, data_len + 1, NULL);

    if (fread (data, sizeof (char), data_len, fd) != data_len) {
        // error
        return -1;
    }

    printf ("%s\n", data);

    fclose (fd);
    free (data);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to use `fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_BEGIN);` to rewind the file.  I'm not sure if the `rewind()` function will close the file or requires the file to be closed.

Comment: Also, you don't need `sizeof(char)`, since the size of `char` is 1 by definition.

Answer (score -1):

Here with a simple doubling method...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void readInput(const char* Path)
{
     ifstream infile;


     infile.open(Path);

     if(!infile.fail())
         cout<<"File opened successfully"<<endl;
     else{
         cout<<"File failed to open"<<endl;
         return;
     }

     int capacity=1000;
     char *arr=new char[capacity];
     char *temp;

     int i=0;

     while(infile >> arr[i])
     {
         i++;
         if ( i >= capacity ) {

             temp = new char[capacity*2];
             std::memcpy(temp , arr, capacity);
             delete [] arr;
             arr = temp;
             capacity *=2;
         }
     }
 }

int main()
{
    char *path="alice.txt";
    readInput(path);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Yes. you are absolutely right. I was just modified small part, now complete, and running.

Comment: This still has the OP's error of continuation when the file failed to open.

Answer (score -2):

The error could when you read and display the array content using the for loop and not on reading the data from file.
Use int instead of short in for loop, as short can increment upto 32768, only.

Comment: What happens if the file is bigger than the capacity of an `int`?

Comment: I answered only what Mujeeb Alam, asked.